# Show the $n$th derivative at $0$ is bounded by $n!$ at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:B_1(0) \rightarrow B_1(0)$ be holomorphic with $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ with

$$a_0=a_1=...=a_{n-1}=0.$$

Show that

$$\vert f^{(n)}(0) \vert \leq n!$$

and
$$\vert f(z) \vert \leq \vert z \vert^n$$

for all $z \in B_1(0)$. Also show if $\vert f^{(n)}(0) \vert =n!$ or if $\vert f(z_0) \vert = \vert z_0 \vert^n$ for some $z_0 \in B_1(0) \setminus \{0\}$ that

$$f(z)=cz^n$$

for some $c \in \Bbb{C}$ such that $\vert c \vert = 1$, for any $z \in B_1(0)$

So my thoughts are that we have

$$f(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n+1}z^{n+1}+a_{n+2}z^{n+2}+...$$

Then taking a derivative yields

$$f'(z)=na_nz^{n-1}+(n+1)a_{n+1}z^n+...$$

I solved it below! upvote if you agree with solution!

Comment: You need to derive $n$ times not just once.

Comment: what would the general $n$th derivative look like @Theorem

Comment: You keep bringing down coefficients which decrease in $1$ each derivation so the first term would become $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 2 z^0$

Comment: ohhhh so all the way up to $n$ we get $n!$? @Theorem as the $z$ term cancels?

Comment: Yes, the rest of the terms will still have $z^{k \geq 1}$ so they are of no interest.

Comment: This is Schwarz Lemma for $f(z)/z^{n-1}$

Comment: and they all go to zero as you plug in zero except for the first term, correct? @Theorem

Comment: @MyMathYourMath Correct

Comment: Cauchy's estimate. Then apply to $g(z) = {f(z) \over z^n}$.

Comment: @copper.hat although I have seen Cauchy's estimate, we have not come across it in this course yet so idk if I can appeal to that :/

Comment: Write $f(z) = z^n g(0)$ and note that $f^{(n)}(0) = n! g(0)$. Show that $|g(0)| \le 1$.

Comment: @Theorem how do I show its less than OR equal to $n!$? I can see the equality side of things just not the less than side of things

Comment: Have you seen the Schwarz lemma?  When $n=0$ this is exactly the Schwarz lemma.  For general $n$ it can be proved in essentially the same way.

Comment: so in the proof do I put $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z^n}$ and $f^{(n)}(0)$ if $z \neq 0$ @EricWofsey

Comment: @copper.hat is my solution correct?

Comment: @Theorem is my solution correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note as
$$a_0=a_1=...=a_{n-1}=0$$
we have that
$$f(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n+1}z^{n+1}+a_{n+2}z^{n+2}+...$$
Taking the $n$th derivative we obtain
$$f^{(n)}(z) = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdot ... \cdot 2z^0+(n+1)(n)(n-1) ...z+(n+2)(n+1)(n)(n-1)...z^2+...$$
and plugging in $0$ yields all terms to become zero except for the first term which is $n!$. Now define
$$g(z):= \begin{cases} 
      \frac{f(z)}{z^n} = a_n + a_{n+1}z + a_{n+2}z^2 & z \neq 0 \\
      \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$
which is holomorphic on all of $B_1(0)$. Now define
$$D_r:=\{z : \vert z \vert^n \le r\}.$$
Then by the maximum principle, for $r<1$, given $z \in D_r$, there exists $z_r \in \partial D_r$ such that
$$\vert g(z) \vert \le \vert g(z_r) \vert =\frac{\vert f(z_r) \vert}{\vert z_r \vert} \le \frac{1}{r}$$
and as $r \rightarrow 1$, we get that
$$\vert g(z) \vert \le 1.$$
This forces
$$\vert f^{(n)}(0) \vert \le n!$$
and
$$\vert f(z) \vert \le \vert z \vert^n.$$
Moreover, suppose equality holds in either one of the above inequalities. Then $\vert g(z) \vert = 1$, then by maximum principle, $g(z)=a$ with $\vert a \vert = 1.$ This forces
$$f(z)=az^n; \space \text{with $\vert a \vert = 1$, $a \in \Bbb{C}$.}$$

Comment: I would define $g(0) = a_n$. Otherwise looks fine.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you upvote my solution then plz

Comment: Did you make the suggested edit?